# Deploying jar to unix server

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, unix, jar

Currently, in order to deploy my program to my ubuntu server, I have to do the following steps.

`1. Compile the code using Gradle
2. Using FileZilla to move the jar to my server.
3. Connect to my server and find the process to kill it
4. restart the program.`

I am curious if there are any alternatives to this that I can try myself. Such as some way to "deploy" my jar to the server and have it automatically restart the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `Jenkins` for automatic deployment.

Answer (score 0):

let's change your work flow:

- Compile the code using Gradle
- writing a dockerfile.
- Using [docker](https://www.docker.com/) build your code into a docker image.
- Push your image to docker registry.
- Connect to your server,  using `docker pull your-docker-image`
- Run `docker run your-docker-image`

step3 & step4 you can use some automatic tools like [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) to control you progress.